# How to set up 2-way syncing between Airtable base and multiple external sources

Tags: postgresql, salesforce, airtable

Is this even possible? I would like to update my companies external postgres database, as well as potentially updating their information in Salesforce, whenever a new record is added in Airtable.

I'd also like to set up a sync so that updates in the postgres database(and again Salesforce possibly) are reflected in Airtable.